# How i can get a value from two associated database table and inserting into select optgroup and option?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to understand how I can get multiple *ID* values from two **MySQL** relational table and set into a *select* *optgroup* as a **value** and its **name** as a title?

HTML Markup:

```
<select name="rays_test" multiple required>
  <option value="1">MRI</option>
  <option value="2">CT Scan</option>
  <optgroup label="X-Ray">
     <option value="1">Skull</option>
     <option value="2">Wrist</option>
     <option value="3">Hip</option>
     <option value="4">Shoulder</option>
     <option value="5">Ankle</option>
     <option value="6">Chest</option>
     <option value="7">Knee</option>
     <option value="8">Spine</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

First table **scan**

[image]

Second Table **scan_extra**

[image]

Must
**X-Ray** *scan_id* in table **scan** is ***3*** associated with column *scan_id* in table **scan_extra**

I try this by PHP, but the result isn't dynamic or not true

```
<select name="rays_test[]" multiple required>
   <?php
      $scan = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM scan LIMIT 2");
         while($urow = mysqli_fetch_array($scan)){
   ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $urow['scan_id']; ?>">
         <?php echo $urow['scan_title']; ?>
      </option>
   <?php
         }
   ?>

   <?php
      $scan = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM scan ORDER BY scan_id DESC LIMIT 1;");
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($scan);
   ?>

   <optgroup label="<?php echo $row['scan_title']; ?>">
      <?php 
         $scan_extra = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM scan_extra");
            while($urow = mysqli_fetch_array($scan_extra)){
      ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $urow['extra_id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $urow['scan_test']; ?>
         </option>
      <?php
            }
      ?>
  </optgroup>                              
</select>
```